# Trying to remember a young adult sci-fy fantasy novel about memory

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, soft-sci-fi

In this book I'm thinking of:

- the main character was a young girl

  - I believe the title showed half of her face and her hair might have looked blackish blue
- her parents grew up in this society where you were taught to memorize everything that you see

  - but her aunt died and asked her mom to take her memories and implant them into her head?
- so the daughter, who grew up in a modern society, thought her mom was her aunt.

I can't remember much else. The book must have been published before 2016, probably years before.

Comment: I cannot help but point out the amusing irony of the title... You cannot remember the title of the book about memory! Mind you I'm not criticising you; I'm not laughing *at you*. When my mum was still working there was a book that employees would write in and one woman once wrote she thought she was losing her memory - and then later on she did it again... I haven't a clue of the book but hopefully someone can help you find your memory again!

Comment: LOL I love me some good irony! thanks for making me smile

Comment: Pryftan at your service.ll

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could this be Margaret Peterson Haddix's *[Escape from Memory](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/303073.Escape_from_Memory)*? It was published in 2005 and has a cover much like you remember.

[image: Book cover - *Escape from Memory*]

> While playing around with hypnotism at a party, Kira remembers fleeing a war-torn country with her mother, speaking a language she can't identify. A few days later her mother disappears, and a woman who calls herself Kira's aunt Memory takes Kira to Crythe, a country that doesn't officially exist, in order to rescue her -- or so she says.
>
> Kira soon learns that Aunt Memory is not what she seems, and Kira and her mother are both in terrible danger. There are memories locked in Kira's mind that could get her and her mother killed. But those memories are the only things that might save them...

[One of the reviews](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/42953793?book_show_action=true) mentions that part of Crythe's culture is memorizing things, and the implanted memories:

> This book was different then anything I've read or heard of. It dived into something that usually isn't even thought about: Memory. Yes, there's some books that has memory in it but it's not the main thing; it's not the thing that drives some characters to do what they did, like it does in this book. The community of Crythe is based on that one thing. Memory is what drives everything that they do and what happens to them, everything. And since Crythe is so important to the story and memory is so important to Crythe, then memory is really important to the story. Plus that's what puts them all in danger in the first place. The fact that Kira has her parents memory in her mind and that's what Rona (first called Aunt Memory) wants so much that she will kill them all to get it. So memory, this thing that is rarly set on center stage in a book, is what drives the whole story and that's original!

I found this by searching for *science fiction young adult book implanted memories aunt mother* although that was not the first set of search terms I tried.

Comment: Oh my god thank you so much! I searched for similar terms but was coming up with more recent books!